# Is it possible to edit a file in whiptail?

Tags: terminal, dialog, whiptail, text-user-interface

For a new TUI, I want to employ whiptail or dialog to make it a bit more visually appealing. Afaik, whiptail is more widely available and even preinstalled on many systems, which is a good reason to use it. (Is that still true?)

But a nice-to-have feature would be to be able to seamlessly edit files in the TUI. In dialog, there is the option `--editbox`.

**Is there something similar for whiptail?** I couldn't find it in the man pages, but it would not be the first time, that I am just not seeing something O_o .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whiptail doesn't do that.  It's designed to imitate an old version of [dialog](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html#h3-Whiptail).  The underlying library (newt) is used by python scripts to implement some more involved user interfaces, but aside from reading the [source code](https://github.com/mlichvar/newt) (and a ***very*** old [tutorial](https://github.com/mlichvar/newt/blob/master/tutorial.sgml)), there's no documentation.